# How to change WordPress sender name?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce

So i want WordPress to send the e-mails with my business mail account and not with the default WordPress one.

This is what i have, it worked for a while but now it´s not, maybe i did something wrong or i deleted some line and now i can´t seem to find what it´s missing?

```
function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'info@supplexstore.com';
}

// Function to change sender name
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'Supplex Store';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add filters are missing.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email');
function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'info@supplexstore.com';
}

// Function to change sender name
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name');
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'Supplex Store';
}
```